# Artin 11.3.3 generator of kernel

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification

I'm working through some problems in Artin's *Algebra* to supplement my problem sheets--finding my rings course quite difficult. Below is my attempt at 11.3.3:

> Find the generator for the kernel of $\phi:\mathbb{R}[x] \rightarrow
> \mathbb{R}$ defined by $x \mapsto (1+\sqrt{2})$.

$g = (x - (1 + \sqrt{2})) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ gets mapped to 0 in $\mathbb{R}[x] $, so bringing $g$ into $\mathbb{Z}[x]^{1}$, we have that $(x - (1 + \sqrt{2}))(x - (1 + \sqrt{2})) = x^2 - 2x - 1$ gets mapped to 0 in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

$x^2 - 2x - 1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x] ^2$. Thus $<x^2 - 2x - 1> \subseteq \ker{\phi}$ is maximal since $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a PID $^3$.

If $<x^2 - 2x - 1>$ were any larger then it would generate the whole ring, since it is maximal. However, the kernel clearly does not generate the entire ring, as the image is not identically 0. Thus $<x^2 - 2x - 1> = \ker{\phi} ^4$.

====

I stitched this together using lecture notes, so even if it correct, I'm not sure I totally understand why. Questions:

> 1. Is there a term for this "computing up" in different rings? I think it's interesting that we went to the bigger ring and then back down for this result.
> 2. Again, why are we using $\mathbb{Q}$ here when the ring of interest is $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?
> 3. Is this just general knowledge? Doesn't seem obvious to me.
> 4. I understand this argument. Is this a strong enough proof?

Comment: Why isn't the kernel generated by your $g$? Also $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is NOT a PID.

Comment: Ah good point. $\phi$ does not map from $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really see any contribution at all from "other rings."  The kernel of the evaluation homomorphism at a real number $r$ over $\Bbb R[x]$ is always going to be $(x-r)$ since $x-r$ is clearly in the kernel.

If the task then becomes to find the kernel of evaluation in $\Bbb Q[x]$ which is apparently an evaluation into $\Bbb Q[r]$, then you might proceed this way:

$$r=1+\sqrt2$$
$$(r-1)=\sqrt 2$$

$$(r-1)^2=2$$

$$r^2-2r-1=0$$

Then we have that $r$ is a root of $x^2-2x-1$, and either that is the minimal polynomial or else it factors into linear factors, one of which is $(x-r)$. But $r$ isn't rational, and so it won't factor, and $\Bbb Q[x]/(x^2-2x-1)\cong \Bbb Q[r]$.